# Inverse of $f(x)=x^n+x$ on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Fix integer $n > 1$. The function $f_n(x) = x^n + x$ is monotone increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and so has an inverse $f_n^{-1}(x)$ that is also monotone increasing on $[0,\infty)$.

I'm interested in properties of $f_n^{-1}(x)$ (in particular, in its Taylor series). I'm sure that it's a well-studied function (or rather, family of functions), but I can't find any literature on it, mostly because I don't know what keywords to use.

Does anyone know a name for this function?

Comment: Taylor series converge on disks, you have a half-open interval, so that's not going to happen in a nice way (it cannot).

Comment: For each fixed $n > 1$ there's an $\varepsilon_n > 0$ so that $f_n(x)$ is monotone increasing on $(-\varepsilon_n,\infty)$ (the positive $(n-1)$st root of $1/n$ will do); so as long as I don't care about uniformity in $n$, there should be no problems with the Taylor series.

Comment: What are you talking about? Monotonicity is not going to necessarily be related to the Taylor series existence. You need to perhaps clarify your question

Comment: Nothing more than this: by extending the domain of $f_n$ to include  an interval around $0$ (while maintaining monotonicity), I'm extending the domain of $f^{-1}$ to include an interval around $0$, so that it makes sense to talk about the $k$th derivative of $f^{-1}$ at $0$, and hence the Taylor series of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @AdamHughes Use complex function theory. For $n\ge2$, the function $f_n$ is analytic with $f_n'(0)=1$. Accordingly, it will have an analytic inverse defined on some neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Yes, I recognize all of that. If you read my original post I'm saying you only get a very small disk of convergence, not nearly enough to talk about $f^{-1}_n(x)$ on the same domain as $f_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a Taylor expansion around the origin exists with positive radius of convergence, say $$f_n^{-1}(y)=:g(y)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_ky^k.$$ Since $g(0)=0$ it follows that $a_0=0$. Consider the relation $$y=g(y)^n+g(y)=\left(\sum_{k\ge 1}a_ky^k\right)^n+\sum_{k\ge 1}a_ky^k $$ which "simplifies" to $$ y= \sum_{k\ge 1}a_ky^k+\sum_{m\ge n}\left(\sum_{k_1+\ldots k_n=m}a_{k_1} \ldots a_{k_n}\right)y^m.$$ Since the latter sum contains monomials of degree $\ge n$ we see right away that $a_1=1$ and $a_2=\ldots a_{n-1}=0$.Let $$c_m= \sum_{k_1+\ldots k_n=m}a_{k_1} \ldots a_{k_n}.$$ The only way $n$ indices $\ge 1$ sum up to $n$ is that $k_1=\ldots k_n=1$, whence $c_n=1$, yielding the coefficient $a_n+1$ for $y^n$ on the RHS. Since this must vanish we have $a_n=-1$.

Continuing like this we see that for $n<m<2n-1$ all the terms in the sum defining $c_m$ involve only products of $a_j$ for $1\le j <n$, therefore $a_m=0$ for $n<m<2n-1$. On the other hand $c_{2n-1}=n\cdot (-1)$ and since $a_{2n-1}+c_{2n-1}=0$ we get $a_{2n-1}=n$.

After this things get more complicated but in principle one can go on and get expressions for further coefficients. All in all, *assuming* $f_n^{-1}$ has a Taylor expansion around zero with positive radius of convergence, it must look like $$g(x)=x-x^n+nx^{2n-1}+\ldots $$ (Actually, $a_{2n}$ must also vanish..)

Comment: Looking at the comments after the question, particularly Harald Hanche-Olsens, I see that we don't have to assume the existence of the Taylor series..

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Teri! I had been working along these lines, and got to the ``things get more complicated but in principle one can go on'' part, at which point I wondered if I was re-inventing the wheel; hence the question.

Comment: By using indetermined coeffients in the expansion in the case $n=3$ it seems $g(x)=x-x^3+3x^5-12x^7+\cdots,$ not matching your prediction of $9$ for the coefficient of $2n-1=5.$

Comment: Oops! when I wrote the line $c_{2n-1}=n\cdot n$ I somehow had in mind that $a_n=n$ (late night scribbling...) But of course $a_n=-1$ and thus $c_{2n-1}=-n$, giving $a_{2n-1}=n$. Will edit accordingly.

Comment: @Teri Now it's right, and I can follow your general argument that $a_{2n-1}=+n.$ I think a few more terms might be obtainable in the general case, before the sums interact too much. +1 on the answer as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

$$f_1^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{2}$$

$$f_2^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{2}(-1 \pm \sqrt{4x+1})$$

$$f_3^{-1}(x) = \frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{27x^2+4}-9x}} - \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{27x^2+4}-9x}}{\sqrt[3]{2} \cdot 3^{2/3}}$$

You can check this answers with [*WolframAlpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20of%20x%5E3%2Bx).

In general $f_n^{-1}(x)$ is the root of polynomial $y^n+y-x$ for $y$.

I don't know if there is a name for this problem.

Comment: Does $f_5^{-1}$ have a closed form?

Comment: Better to ask Galois.

Comment: @columbus8myhw No - if it did then the quintic $y^n+y+d=0$ would be solvable for all rational $d$, but it's not too hard to produce examples of this form which are unsolvable (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring%E2%80%93Jerrard_normal_form#Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_normal_form for an example).

Comment: Yes, and what is the downvote for?